# Accidental assignment error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm facing a strange accidental assignment error on the line `if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){` The code's output is always FALSE so I'm unable to query my database. I'm not sure why it is happening. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance :)

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "apple", "apple", "apple");
if (!$con) {
    die("cannot connect: " . mysqli_error());
}
 else {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $btnNum = $_GET['btnNum'];
        mysqli_select_db($con, "apple");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM resume where resume_id ='" . $id . "' AND button_match ='" . $btnNum . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error, query failed');
        if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $name = $row['resume_title'];
            $type = $row['file_type'];
            $content = $row['resume_data']; //content of file
            $size = $row['file_size']; //file size
            header('Content-Type:"' . $type . '"');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
            echo $content;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the connection & query for errors.

Comment: If you connect directly to your database using ``mysql`` and run the same query, what do you see? I.e. run ``mysql -P 3306 -u apple --password="apple" apple <<< "SELECT * FROM resume WHERE resume_id = X AND button_match = 'Y'"`` for appropriate X and Y.

Comment: I mean if it returs false then query has to be invalid. Check it. Maybe you have SQL errors

Comment: is `btnNum` set up as a numeric or a string type in the database?

Comment: Also do note, that your code is exploitable by [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I'm getting a  " MySQL returned an empty result set" message but my table does contain data

Comment: your table may contain data but you have also "where" clause which limits data to some conditions. Print this query and execute it directly on DB then you will see if it returns results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking of assignment errors, there are NO assignment errors in this expression.

`fetch_array()` returns `null` when there are no [more] results to fetch.

Speaking of your particular problem, check your query, database credentials, typos and such. Then double-check.

Also, unrelated but lot more important than this simple typo: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/)
Also, bear in mind [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die/15320411#15320411)

Comment: it returns null not false